# Complicated Where query in Laravel/MongoDB

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, where-clause

I have an array(or collection) like this for my **notifications**. Each notification has an **array field** for all users who has seen the notification.

```
    array:2 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "_id" => "604485ddf92e0000050079c6"
    "title" => "Notification title"
    "message" => "Notification message"
    "type" => "success"
    "expire_date" => "2021-05-09T19:30:00.000000Z"
    "read_by_users" => array:2 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "user_id" => "601fd68d212200006f001c0b"
        "seen_time" => 1615103466
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "user_id" => "60365402546900008a007c76"
        "seen_time" => "1615103466"
      ]
    ]
    "updated_at" => "2021-03-07T07:50:53.314000Z"
    "created_at" => "2021-03-07T07:50:53.314000Z"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "_id" => "604497d2f92e0000050079c7"
    "title" => "Next Notification title"
    "message" => "Next Notification message"
    "type" => "success"
    "expire_date" => "2021-05-09T19:30:00.000000Z"
    "read_by_users" => array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "user_id" => "601fd68d212200006f001c0b"
        "seen_time" => 1615187929
      ]
    ]
    "updated_at" => "2021-03-07T09:07:30.066000Z"
    "created_at" => "2021-03-07T09:07:30.066000Z"
  ]
]
```

Now I want to get notifications **where** has not seen by current user (for example with this user_id 60365402546900008a007c76).
Any solution would be apreciated .
My project is in Laravel 8 and MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result using array here is a solution

```
$userId = '60365402546900008a007c76'; $notifications = [];
        foreach ($data as $notification) {
         $userIds = array_column($notification['read_by_users'], 'user_id');
        
         if (!in_array($userId, $userIds)) {
             $notifications [] = $notification;
         }
dd($notifications);
```